Kubernetes HPA not working with Datadog metric
I am trying to autoscale PODs based on custom metric from DatadogMetric. I have followed the documentation on Datadog to create a DatadogMetric and the use it in your HPA as External metric. My DatadogMetric.yaml and hpa.yaml looks like this
-------DatadogMetric.yaml-------------
apiVersion: datadoghq.com/v1alpha1
kind: DatadogMetric
metadata:
  name: user-count
  namespace: {{ .Values.Namespace }}
spec
  query: <my_custom_metric_query_here>

---------hpa.yaml---------------
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 2
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: name-{{ $.Values.Name }}-0
  metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
      metric:
        name: datadogmetric@{{.Values.Namespace }}:user-count
      target:
        type: Value
        value: 2


I am getting below error
The HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get external metric <metric_name>:user-count/nil: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: Internal error occurred: DatadogMetric not found for metric name: ...
I am following this documentation
https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/guide/cluster_agent_autoscaling_metrics/?tab=helm#create-the-datadogmetric-object
